# How to use images correctly even the camara is captured in reverce direction iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, image-capture

In my App I have used captured images in two locations,

1. ***`view1`***: Immmidiatly use/set in imageView1 after capture the image.
2. ***`view2`***: **Re use imageview1.image in an imageView2** in 2nd view.

in first image view1 the image is set properly even we take in **reverse direction,**

But in 2nd Image when we reuse the `imageviw1.image` It set in reverse direction.

How to reuse the image as it is?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
[UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref scale:[rep scale] orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[rep orientation]];
```

**Example:**

```
typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)(ALAsset *asset);
typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)(NSError *error);  

ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
    if (iref) {

        UIImage *images  = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref scale:[rep scale] orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[rep orientation]];


    }                               
};


ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
{


};    

NSURL *asseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fileURL"];
assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:asseturl 
               resultBlock:resultblock
              failureBlock:failureblock];
```